# Azure CLI can't execute commands - keeps saying credentials have expired

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Every time I try to run a command from the Azure CLI, I am returned with an error stating my credentials have expired. This can happen immediately after I logout then log back in and try to run any sort of command. Here's an example below:

```
user:~ $ azure group show resourcename
info:    Executing command group show
+ Listing resource groups                                                      
error:   Credentials have expired, please reauthenticate.
         Detailed error message from ADAL is as follows: Error: Entry not found in cache.
info:    Error information has been recorded to /Users/me/.azure/azure.err
error:   group show command failed
```

Comment: Problem solved; apparently this is a known issue and solution is listed under the GH issues for the Azure CLI: https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure CLI can lose the credentials after a period of time 
All you need to do is to login again using the CLI command :

```
— azure login  --username <Your Username>
```

It will prompt for a password and would be good to go from there

Also if you open the azure.err file you will see the specific exception details

Comment: I'll accept as answer but should also note that there appears to be a "known issue" with the tool (see my comment under my question that links to a GH issue on the project page)